# Implement If condition in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I am new to PHP function. I think following problem can be solved using function. Here I am able to store html form data in database which is passed from ajax using following code. But I am little bit confused where to implement if condition. If Data has been submitted, I want to stop data replication.

**My working php code**

```
if(isset($_POST["section_name"])){
 $section_name = $_POST["section_name"];
 $class_id = $_POST["class_id"];

 for($count = 0; $count<count($section_name); $count++)
 {
     $query =$con->prepare('INSERT INTO section(class_id, section_name) VALUES (:class_id, :section_name)');
     $query->bindParam(':class_id', $class_id);
     $query->bindParam(':section_name', $section_name[$count]);
     $query->execute();
     echo "Section has been assigned";
     }   

     }
```

Now, I want to include above code in following else condition.

```
 $query =$con->query('SELECT * FROM section');
    while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    if(($_POST["class_id"]==$row["class_id"])&&($_POST["section_name"]==$row["section_name"])){
        echo "Section has already assigned in this class ";

    }
    else{
        // insert...
    }
    }
```

When I try to merge code, I can't handle. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pretty much everything, you just need to wrap it in a function like this:

```
function insert() {
    if(isset($_POST["section_name"])){
        $section_name = $_POST["section_name"];
        $class_id = $_POST["class_id"];

        for($count = 0; $count<count($section_name); $count++)
        {
            $query =$con->prepare('INSERT INTO section(class_id, section_name) VALUES (:class_id, :section_name)');
            $query->bindParam(':class_id', $class_id);
            $query->bindParam(':section_name', $section_name[$count]);
            $query->execute();
            echo "Section has been assigned";
        }   

    }
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
$query =$con->query('SELECT * FROM section');
while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
if(($_POST["class_id"]==$row["class_id"])&&($_POST["section_name"]==$row["section_name"])){
    echo "Section has already assigned in this class ";

}
else{
    insert();
}
}
```

Comment: thanks it works, but echo message is looping more than once. How to echo outside of loop. So it would be echo only once

Comment: just put it outside the for loop.

Comment: Oh no, I just see database, It has inserted same data twice and more. I think problem is caused calling function within while loop. How to solve ?

Comment: Instead of querying for all the records, you should use a WHERE clause comparing class_id, section_name.  If it return records you know it already exists, if not then you do the insert.